# Asymmetric encryption: changing my private key

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption

Obviously I don't understand asymm encryption well enough.

So in any asymm encryption system, I can ask for a key, which generates for me a private key which I should keep private and a public key which I should widely publicize.

But of course I can never be absolutely sure that my private key has not been compromised, no matter how I store it. So, like a password, I want to change my private key often.

My question is, in any asymm encryption system: whenever I make a new private key, I get a new public key too, right? So my old public key will not work with my new private key? ...which would mean anyone who wants to communicate with me using my encryption will have to first get my new public key, right?

Or is there any way of changing my private key often without requiring my friends to constantly get an update of my public key?

Answer (score 3):

With asymmetrical encryption algorithms, the public and private keys are mathematically related to each other. You cannot change one key without changing the other as well.

As long as you take reasonable measures to protect your private key though, you should rarely need to change it.

- Use a large enough key to help prevent it being cracked in the foreseeable future. (size depends on the algorithm, 4096-bit RSA for example.)
- Don't store your private key anywhere online.
- Store your private key in an encrypted container that is password protected. Make the password long, complex, and **memorize** it.
- Never use your private key on a system you suspect could be compromised.
- Consider storing the key completely offline, like on a memory stick or CD (in the encrypted container of course).

These are the minimum that I would personally do.

And if you just happen to be concerned about people having an authentic copy of your public key, generate it's hash and provide a way for people to confirm the hash with you.

When it comes down to it though, the question of whether your keys and communication are secure enough is based on what you're defending against. If you think your system is compromised and the private key is being stolen off your system, then changing your keys frequently is pointless because the new keys will be stolen as well. If you believe your public key has been used to crack your private key, larger keys and better entropy will result in them taking longer to crack.

The current (2012) [NIST recommendations](http://www.keylength.com/en/4/) for asymmetric keys is to change them every 1-2 years, and to use a minimum key size of 2048 bits.

Comment: ...and do not distribute your public key through insecure means.

Comment: @Tarik Public keys are usually meant to be public.  As long as they can be verified through a fingerprint or trusted certificate or trusted signature, it is perfectly fine to distribute in any way you want.  Secure sites on the web distribute their public keys through their certificates as part of the SSL handshake.  This [question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/406/how-should-i-distribute-my-public-key) gives some more details on distributing public keys.

Comment: @gtrig Thanks for re-explaining what I already explained to the guy who asked the question. I believe the matter of public key distribution and the necessary measures to avoid known attacks were indeed relevant. See comments below...

Comment: Additionally you could keep the private key in a smart card or secure token. Obviously your signing/decryption application then has to support smart card operations...

Comment: cannot see how your do-s and dont-s answer the question, mainly "You cannot change one key without changing the other as well." is wrong

Answer (score 2):

As far as I been taught, Yes, it is possible to change the private key without changing the public key. 
If {e, n} is the public key (n is the product of two large prime number) and {d,n} is the private key. Then we need to find a new value of e such that m=c^(ed) mod n. This is achieved by solving ed=kx phi(n) +1, where phi(n) is the Eulers Totient function. 
The reason to change the private key is if we believe that the keys have been compromised so we need a new key, but we need to keep the old public key for legacy reasons.

Comment: would suggest this as accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Syon made some excellent points.  Another thing to consider is having multiple keys.  It is strongly recommended to have a separate key for signing and a separate key for encrypting.

If you private encrypting key is ever compromised, your signatures are still valid.

And to elaborate on one of Syon's points, you can create and store a private key on a hardware device such as a [SafeNet eToken](http://www.safenet-inc.com/products/data-protection/two-factor-authentication/etoken-pro/).  The private key cannot be extracted, so as long as you have physical possession of the token, you can be very confident that your private key is safe.

Answer (score -1):

You perfectly understood how it works. There is no way to change your private key without changing your public key. Now, the problem is that if you distribute your public key through insecure means, you can fall pray to a man in the middle attack.

See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack for an example.

The way to avoid this attack is to get a digital certificate from a trusted entity.

Comment: Which means that an adversary is spoofing my system identity, impersonating me, and encrypting his messages with my public key so that my friend (the recipient) thinks his words were mine?

Comment: The adversary sends a fake public key that he made up. Your friend uses it. The adversary decrypts the message then reencrypts it using your real public key.

Comment: There's no reason you cannot freely distribute your public key. As long as someone knows that they have your _real_ public key, there is no appreciable risk of a MITM attack. As for using a certificate from a trusted entity, that wouldn't prevent a "fake public key" because it's totally dependent on who your "friend" trusts. If your certificate were signed by authority A, and an attacker created a fake copy of your certificate signed by authority B, and your friend trusts both A and B...

Comment: How would they know that they have your real public key? A phone call? Physically meeting them? i. e. OOBA (Out of band authentication),  which may or may not be practical.

Comment: @Syon Trusted authorities such as Verisign have policies to create certificates. Class three certificates issuance require physical presence and an official identification ID card or equivalent. So, the scenario you describe cannot work. Of course, security depends among other things on the education, awareness and  training of the parties involved so as to not have them trust just any certificate.

Comment: If complete and total certainty of the public keys authenticity is necessary, and there really is a risk of MITM, then some extra authentication of the key is necessary. Consider who/what would have the resources and ability to reliably perform the type of MITM attack you're describing. The government can compel an authority like Verisign to create a fake certificate if they choose to.

Comment: Regardless though, the comments of SO aren't really the place for a drawn out discussion on this. I suggest we agree to disagree and let OP decide on the information at hand.

Comment: @Syon to paraphrase you "consider who/what would have the resources and ability" to crack 512 bit keys before even thinking about 1024 or more. Besides, I believe I provided relevant info to the question that you decided to challenge, which is OK since it has brought up interesting points also relevant to the topic. Now, I do not quite understand why OP have to be involved at this point to kind of police this discussion. Fine for me though...